# Why does Auth0 login screen does not return to UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, auth0

Using the [Auth0 UWP sample app](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/windows-uwp-csharp/01-login) as-is I am getting "forbidden" error.

Populating appUri (ms-app//...) to "redirectUri" fixes this issue (code snippet below) and I am able to log in to my Google account using the Auth0 login screen.

```
string appUri = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();

             Auth0Client client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
             {
                 Domain = domain,
                 ClientId = clientId,
                 RedirectUri = appUri //added

             });
```

Problem is that after the login screen disappears, it does not return to the app. Instead, a Windows App Store prompt is displayed with the message "You'll need a new app to open this ms-app link".

[image: ms-app link problem]

Why is redirect not working?

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2019 v16.3.10
- Auth0.OidcClient.UWP v3.1.0
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.2.9

Comment: I could reproduce your issue. Strangely, this problem did not occur in earlier versions, I have tested with Auth0 (version 2.40).

Comment: There seems to be some contradiction in this question. It states "Using the Auth0 UWP sample app as-is" which at the time of writing this question was using Auth0.OidcClient.UWP v2.4.0 yet it lists v3.1.0 in the question.

Either way the sample has been updated and it appears to be working now.

Comment: No code changes, only nuget package updated to the latest version is what I meant... Anyway the issue is fixed in the latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does Auth0 login screen does not return to UWP app

For my testing, the issue occur in Auth0 latest version, And it work when I  reduce the version to 2.43.

```
Auth0ClientOptions clientOptions = new Auth0ClientOptions
{
    Domain = "dev-sosxxos2.auth0.com",
    ClientId = "Pir5MkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxvL07W",
};

client = new Auth0Client(clientOptions); 
await client.LoginAsync();
```

Please note you need to configure **Allowed Logout URLs** and **Allowed Callback URLs** with app sid in **Auth0** app setting page and set `Application` Type as **Native**

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri());
```

Comment: Thanks, downgrading to 2.43 fixes the issues